# What is the name of this pink rose with a button form bloom?

Tags: identification, flowers, roses

I don't know what variety this rose is.  Can you please tell me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the centifolia or moss rose ['Anais Segalas'](https://garden.org/plants/view/594/Rose-Rosa-Anais-Segalas/). A beautiful rose from the mid 1800's.

[image]